# Is there a way to use tf.data.Dataset inside of another Dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm doing segmentation. Each training sample have multiple images with  segmentation masks. I'm trying to write `input_fn` to merge all mask images in to one for each training sample. 
I was planning on using two `Datasets`, one that iterates over samples folders and another that reads all masks as one large batch and then merges them to one tensor.

I'm getting an error when nested `make_one_shot_iterator` is called. I Know that this approach is a bit of a stretch and mostlikely datasets wheren't designed for such usage. But then how should I approach this problem so that I avoid using tf.py_func?

Here is a simplified version of the dataset:

```
def read_sample(sample_path):
    masks_ds = (tf.data.Dataset.
        list_files(sample_path+"/masks/*.png")
        .map(tf.read_file)
        .map(lambda x: tf.image.decode_image(x, channels=1))
        .batch(1024)) # maximum number of objects
    masks = masks_ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return tf.reduce_max(masks, axis=0)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.glob("../input/stage1_train/*"))
ds.map(read_sample)
# ...
sample = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
# ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the nested dataset has only a single element, you can use [`tf.contrib.data.get_single_element()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/get_single_element) on the nested dataset instead of creating an iterator:

```
def read_sample(sample_path):
    masks_ds = (tf.data.Dataset.list_files(sample_path+"/masks/*.png")
                .map(tf.read_file)
                .map(lambda x: tf.image.decode_image(x, channels=1))
                .batch(1024)) # maximum number of objects
    masks = tf.contrib.data.get_single_element(masks_ds)
    return tf.reduce_max(masks, axis=0)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.glob("../input/stage1_train/*"))
ds = ds.map(read_sample)
sample = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

In addition, you can use the [`tf.data.Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map), [`tf.data.Dataset.interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave), or [`tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) transformationw to perform a nested `Dataset` computation inside a function and flatten the result into a single `Dataset`. For example, to get all of the samples in a single `Dataset`:

```
def read_all_samples(sample_path):
    return (tf.data.Dataset.list_files(sample_path+"/masks/*.png")
            .map(tf.read_file)
            .map(lambda x: tf.image.decode_image(x, channels=1))
            .batch(1024)) # maximum number of objects

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.glob("../input/stage1_train/*"))
ds = ds.flat_map(read_all_samples)
sample = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```